# Add, update and retrieve userform entries

Tags: excel, vba

Take a look at my design first because i have to Add, update and retrieve supplier details such as company name, business address, contact number etc. And when i click add button. must i really need to link to another form which is StudentSubjectForm. My question is i need to know what codes to write in update and retrieve button. Please give me the basics.

My design consists of add, update and retrieve button. with a 3 textbox and 3 labels.

[image]

And these are my codes when i click add button.

```
Private Sub AddButton_Click()

 Dim companyName As String
 Dim companyAddress As String
 Dim contactNo As String

    companyName = CompanyNameTextBox.Text
    companyAddress = CompanyAddressTextBox.Text
    contactNo = ContactNumberTextBox.Text

    'To transfer student details to StudentSubjectForm window
    StudentSubjectForm.StudentNameDisplayLabel.Caption = studentName
    StudentSubjectForm.AdmissionNoDisplayLabel.Caption = admissionNo
    StudentSubjectForm.CourseDisplayLabel.Caption = courseName
    'To show the student subject form
    StudentSubjectForm.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: You have two End Sub lines, that will cause an issue.  Otherwise, is there something specific that's not working?  Are you getting an error or unexpected results?  I guess I'm not really seeing a question here...

Comment: hmm. there is no error when i put 2 end sub. my question is since i need to input company name, address and contact number and then click add. Must i also link it to another form. or i just remove the entire lines from 'to transfer student details to studentsubjectform.show. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try it and see what happens?  If the form is in memory, it should work (I haven't tested this) but if the form hasn't been created yet, I don't know if what you've done will work.  Honestly, try and and see what happens.  It'll be much quicker than asking on a forum.

Comment: it works though. and besides that i have another question to ask if you don mind. can you give me a few guide lines on what should i put in my update and retrieve codes? like how am i going to start?

Comment: Could you retitle your thread to reflect what your question is about?

Comment: Seems like this is more of a question for codereview: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This isn't really the right venue for a discussion but...One way to go about it would be to store the values in a worksheet cell and then call them back when you want to populate the other form.  So rather than "StudentSubjectForm.StudentNameDisplayLabel.Caption = studentName"  you could use "Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = studentName" in you AddButton event and in the StudentSubjectForm_Initialization() event you could do StudentSubjectForm.StudentNameDisplayLabel.Caption = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a static data structure to organize your company data? Regardless of your question, this might help keep things clear.

```
Type xCompanyData
    Name As String
    Address As String
    Number As String
End Type
```

Then... for multiple companies, make instances of CompanyData...

```
Dim CompanyData() As xCompanyData
' # companies? = n
ReDim CompanyData(1 To n)

'example
CompanyData(1).Name = 'userdata form stuff here
```

Comment: wow thanks  a lot. This really answers my question. but what if i don want to link to another form. is okay right?

Comment: I'd appreciate an upvote then.
Yes, you do not need to link to another form. Just name your variables appropriately and the Type will behave as expected

Comment: so the type xcompanydata, i can just give any name i want?

Comment: Yes, the type xcompanydata could be named whatever you'd like.

Comment: 1 last question for this 'example
CompanyData(1).Name = 'userdata form stuff here.                                        i have to create a userdata form? because i not very sure what to give. thanks.